# How to read Whole url or Read URL parameters using ZOHO Creator form script?

Tags: zoho

**Zoho Creator's Question**

How to read Whole url or Read URL parameters using form script ?

We need url's parameter for parameter value in form.

Comment: Good Question Bro

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to read the URL parameter to set a field in the form, it may not be required to read the url. While passing the param, it's enough to mention the deluge name of the field and Creator will automatically set the field value to the param being passed.

Url: 
app_url#Form:New_Form?**New_field**=**Creator**

Here **New_Field** is the deluge name of the field and **Creator** is the value to be set. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: How to Fetch New_field's value = Creator in onload form with selected dropdown value